# Applying the test for divergence to $2/\sqrt{n} + (-1)^{n}/3^{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question asks to determine whether the series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}})$$

I first want to apply the test for divergence. 
$$let f(x) =(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{(-1)^x}{3^{x+1}}) $$ so that it will be valid to apply L'Hospitals rule. Then
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{(-1)^x}{3^{x+1}})$$
$$= 0 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^x}{3^{x+1}}$$

now if we try apply L'Hospitals rule in the numerator that derivative would be $ln(-1)(-1)^x$ which clearly cannot happen as ln of a negative number is undefined. Does this mean that the test for divergence is inconclusive as $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{(-1)^x}{3^{x+1}})$ does not exist?

Comment: I am not sure where L'Hospital's Rule come into play. The first part is divergent (integral test)

Comment: Also to apply L'Hospitals rule the function needs to be differentiable, which as you pointed out it isn't.

Comment: I am wanting to apply test for divergence to the series. Taking $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^x}{3^{x+1}}$$ is the part i am unsure of. $n \to \infty$ of $(-1)^n$ is indeterminate and $n \to \infty \frac{1}{3^(x+1)}$ will be infinity. So then we will have the form indeterminate/infinity

Comment: I guess I'm asking how to apply the test for divergence in this case and write mathematically that it is not possible to take the limit to infinity of the sequence (hence the series is not divergent)?

Comment: You don't need l'Hôpital's Rule; $\lim\sup\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}=\lim\inf\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}=0$.

Comment: Alternating series test?

Comment: the sum diverges by the comparison test